# Google Cloud Shell Editor not loading the resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

When I open the Google Cloud Shell Code Editor it is not loading the resources and hence I am unable to work. I have attached a screenshot below with a view of the developer tools console. Please help me out. Thanks.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Use Chrome, Google is always trying to pull you to its world.

Comment: @MohamedBenchohra Firefox works fine (I'm connected to a GCP VM instance as I type this from Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be related to an internal project/billing configuration. Since this kind of access errors are thrown when the accounts have payment issues, I think that you should firstly [verify that your billing account is in a good status](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/view-linked); however, if you continue getting these error messages after this validation, I suggest you to take a look the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#bug_reports) tool that you can use to raise a [Cloud Shell ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187188&template=0) in order to verify this scenario with the Google Technical Support Team.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things could cause this:

1. **An interfering browser extension**

   Are you using any browser extensions that could be interfering
   (e.g., an ad blocker)
2. **A bug.**

   As @Armin_SC suggested, use [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#bug_reports) to file an issue in this case.

As a workaround, you might want to try [gcloud compute ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) to connect to your instances.